# Can shellcode run on 32bit, 64bit both windows operating systems?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, shellcode

Is there any way to run 32bit shellcode on 64bit operating system?
I intend to run 32bit shellcode on 64bit process.  Is it possible?
I am sure that I have to build 32bit, 64bit shellocdes, and run it on equal bits process.
I know, the main point is the size of address, the differences between `0x00000000` and `0x00000000 00000000`. My post seems too poor, but how can I express more about my question?  Please edit my question and answer me.

Comment: If the process is running in 64-bit ("long") mode, then your shellcode will execute in that mode too.  So it had better be written to run properly in 64-bit mode.  In principle, if you write the code carefully, it might also be able to run in 32-bit mode, but what would be the point?

Comment: @NateEldredge, could you please tell me more about it? Have you got any reference? I cannot understand "if you write the code carefully, it might also be able to run in 32-bit mode.". Is it possible? If it is, please give me a reference.

Comment: You choose your instructions carefully so that the same sequence of bytes represents valid code in either mode (though it may not do exactly the same thing).  I don't know a reference for this; I think it's common sense.  But you already know what mode the code will run in, so there is no purpose in making it also able to run in the other mode.  I really don't understand why you're trying to do what you say.